# Send bash array for loop to the background

Tags: bash, shell

For every item in an array I want to execute same command.

```
cat dummy.sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a LIST=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
for ITEM in ${LIST[@]}; do
   sleep $ITEM
   for i in $(seq 2); do
      echo $ITEM
   done
done
```

This is an example, but such loop doesn't work either. I want to send every `for ITEM in ${LIST[@]}; do` (commands for every item in an array) to the background so they be executed at the same time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you know that you need to use the `&` char after the command to send it to the background? Good luck.

Comment: Yes I do, but I tried putting `&` after `echo $ITEM &`, `done &`, `done &` or `./dummy.sh &` - I can't find the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) inside the loop, and then `wait` for the child processes to complete:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

for ITEM in ${LIST[@]}; do
    (
        sleep $ITEM
        for i in $(seq 2); do
            echo $ITEM
        done
    ) &
done

wait
```